# mSSQL, SQL view, select, percentage query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, percentage, calculation

So this is the requirement I need to meet:
Aggregated data of all the schools in the ESD, grouped by

> SchoolDistrict.SchoolDistrictID

(get the same data as the school district scenario above, then add grouping by district, filtered to

> EducationServiceDistrict. EducationServiceDistrictID

)
Also calculate percentage of pass, fail, and untested

How do I calculate the percentage pass, fail, and untested?
This is the query I have written so far.

```
CREATE VIEW district_map AS  
 SELECT * and SchoolDistrictID, 
        EducationServiceDistrict
   FROM SchoolDistrict_View  
         and SchoolDistrict, 
        EducationServiceDistrict
  GROUP BY EducationServiceDistrict.EducationServiceDistrictID  
  ORDER BYLeadWaterTestLocation.PassFail
```

Comment: Your SQL statement is invalid (it has a syntax error), so it can't be doing anything. You calculate the percentage the same way you would anywhere else, by division using the total number of grades, the count of those that failed, those that passed, or those that were untested. Also, when you added the SQL tag, you were shown a large red box that suggested you add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, because functionality and syntax varies widely between them. By ignoring that suggestion, you've simply added a delay getting help while people wait for you to add it before answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the general idea of how these problems are solved - if you understand this simplified version you will be able to solve your problem.

```
    select d.districtName,
    s.studentCount,
    case when s.studentCount=0 then 0 else s.passed / s.studentCount * 100 end as PassedPct
    from district d 
    join (select districtId,
          sum(studentCount) as studentCount,
          sum(passed) as passed
          from schools
          group by districtId) as s
    on d.districtId = s.districtId
    order by d.districtName
```